# Java Calculator Not Functioning

Tags: java, calculator

I am new to programming.
I Even made this code using help.
I Want to know why it is not executing successfully..
When I tried to execute it, then I have to type the number twice to make it Run.
And the yes or no exit does not work either!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Cal{

public static void main (String[] args)
{


    String i;
    char   in;
    int    sol;
    int    x;
    int    y;


    System.out.println("Hello! \nWelcome to The Calculator");
    System.out.println("Use the following Commands to use The Calulator, \nType the following letters: \na for Addition \ns for Subtraction \nm for for Multipication \nd for Division" );

    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

do
{


    System.out.println("Now enter the letter for you operation: ");
    keyIn.nextLine();

    i = keyIn.nextLine();



    in = i.charAt(0);

    if (in == 'a')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in the first number ");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Type in the second number ");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x + y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }

    if (in == 's')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in your first number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Type in the second number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x - y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }


    if (in == 'm')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in your first number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Type in the second number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x * y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }


    if (in == 's')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in your first number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Type in the second number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x / y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }

    System.out.println("Do you want to do another calculation? No:n Yes:y");
    keyIn.nextLine();

}

while(keyIn.equals("y"));
if (keyIn.equals("n"));

    System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you have `keyIn.nextLine()` twice each time, `keyIn.nextInt()` twice each time, etc.

Comment: Your exit test does not work because you ask "do you want another calculation" and then read their answer. If it's not "y" you then call `keyIn.equals` again, which expects the user to type another answer. Just get rid of the entire final `if` block, because is they don't type "y" you want the program to terminate, and that happens when the `main` method ends anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
System.out.println("Type in your first number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();
```

you call keyIn.nextInt() twice. Since you don't store the first result in a variable it is lost.

You could easily find that out by yourself using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You keep doing:

` keyIn.nextLine();

i = keyIn.nextLine();`

That's why you have to put in two inputs. The first input is wasted and then the second one stores the input.

Remove the first keyIn.nextLine(); and just leave:

'i = keyIn.nextLine();`

Where ever you use it.

As that stores the unit and let's your program evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, and check out the comments:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Cal

{

public static void main (String[] args)
{


    String i;
    char   in;
    int    sol;
    int    x;
    int    y;



    System.out.println("Hello! \nWelcome to The Calculator");
    System.out.println("Use the following Commands to use The Calulator, \nType the following letters: \na for Addition \ns for Subtraction \nm for for Multipication \nd for Division" );

    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

do
{


    System.out.println("Now enter the letter for you operation: ");
    //keyIn.nextLine();

    i = keyIn.nextLine(); // key input saved in variable!



    in = i.charAt(0);

    if (in == 'a')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in the first number ");
    //keyIn.nextInt(); // key input would be lost here..
    x = keyIn.nextInt();  // key input saved in variable

    System.out.println("Type in the second number ");
    //keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x + y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }

    if (in == 's')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in your first number");
    //keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Type in the second number");
    //keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x - y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }


    if (in == 'm')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in your first number");
    //keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Type in the second number");
    //keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x * y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }


    if (in == 's')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in your first number");
    //keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Type in the second number");
    //keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x / y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }



    System.out.println("Do you want to do another calculation? No:n Yes:y");
    keyIn.nextLine();



}

while(keyIn.equals("y"));
if (keyIn.equals("n"));

    System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Yes thanks guys for that!
but how to make my **exit test** work the _yes_ and _no_?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit. Try following:

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
{


    String i;
    char   in;
    int    sol;
    int    x;
    int    y;



    System.out.println("Hello! \nWelcome to The Calculator");
    System.out.println("Use the following Commands to use The Calulator, \nType the following letters: \na for Addition \ns for Subtraction \nm for for Multipication \nd for Division" );

    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

do
{


    System.out.println("Now enter the letter for you operation: ");
    keyIn.nextLine();

    i = keyIn.nextLine();



    in = i.charAt(0);

    if (in == 'a')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in the first number ");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Type in the second number ");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x + y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }

    if (in == 's')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in your first number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Type in the second number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x - y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }


    if (in == 'm')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in your first number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Type in the second number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x * y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }


    if (in == 's')
    {


    System.out.println("Type in your first number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    x = keyIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Type in the second number");
    keyIn.nextInt();
    y = keyIn.nextInt();
    sol = x / y;

    System.out.println("You chose + operation. \nAnswer = " + sol);
    }



    System.out.println("Do you want to do another calculation? No:n Yes:y");
    keyIn.nextLine();
}while(keyIn.equals("y"));
}
```